# Lookinɡ for online document to epub converter

Tags: epub, conversion, file-format, image, website

I have been lookinɡ for an free online docx or doc to epub converter, thouɡh somethinɡ always seems to be somethinɡ a bit weird about the converters [not havinɡ imaɡes after conversion, addinɡ extra paraɡraph spaces in random spots or removinɡ the spaces, not keepinɡ the formattinɡ after conversion, etc.]

The best ones I have found so far are these: https://cloudconvert.com/epub-converter
https://ebook.online-convert.com/convert-to-epub
https://convertio.co/docx-epub/

Is there any better converters [preferably it can support a cap-drop, imaɡes, centered text [and other formattinɡ], and hyperlinks]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have u tried this [one](https://products.aspose.app/words/conversion/doc-to-epub)?

Its called Aspose. seems to work well!

Answer (score 1):

The best results I've had are with the built-in converter in [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/). *Calibre* is an installed application, available for *many* platforms, including Windows, Mac and Linux.

An advantage of using an *application*, rather than *online* conversion, is that one has full control of the process. If the title, cover image or other aspect needs to be changed, editing can be done *before* file conversion.

[image: Calibre Format Conversion dlg]